# Switch from Arch to Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I'm planning to switch from Arch to Ubuntu, since stability is more important than latest version for me. However, I'm having some troubles since I have a lot of stuff in my home directory and the home directory is in the same partition as the binaries. I didn't see any option in Ubuntu guided setup to preserve the home directory. Is there any way I can get around this? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Backups are your best friends, whether or not you switch a distro.

Comment: Ubuntu will *try* to preserve your /home as long as you don't reformat. But there's no guarantee. One miskey with the installer and everything's gone.  Backups are indeed your best friends.

Comment: Trying to keep /home is probably not a good idea anyway since config files, etc will likely be for different versions/build options of even the same programs. Recommend to backup to offline media and reformat during install.